# LDAP sync between Win2008 and Cisco Unified Call Manager

Tags: ldap, call-manager

I have a VOIP environment with Win 2008 as a primary LDAP server.
However, before I setup Cisco Unified Call Manager to get LDAP sync from Win 2008, previous administrator has created users in CUCM 9.1 without integrating with Win 2008 first.

Because of that, I have accounts that exist in Win 2008 that don't exist in CUCM and users in CUCM that do not exist in Win 2008 LDAP. It seems the previous admin managed the accounts manually on both sides.

Is there a way to merge the two? Or is manually adding to Win 2008 the only solution?

Would this be the best to minimize downtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it up in a way where there's only one AD server around Call Manager and Windows Server 2008.

Once you setup the Call Manager to fetch LDAP data from Windows Server 2008 without creating one for its own, the Call Manager's side of adding/modifying certain properties of accounts will be greyed out.

For example, Call Manager will automatically disable an account that hasn't been synced from Windows LDAP.